# Creating .mat file from images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mat

I want to run the following codes.

```
load('DatasColor_38.mat','DATA'); % to load the dataset used in this example

% the information to split data between training and test set
DIV = DATA{3};
DIM1 = DATA{4};
DIM2 = DATA{5};
lab = DATA{2}; % label
NX = DATA{1}; % cell array that stores the image

fold=1;  % in this example only the first fold has been used

trainPattern = (DIV(fold, 1:DIM1));       % id of the training patterns
testPattern = (DIV(fold, DIM1+1:DIM2));   % id of the test patterns
y = lab(DIV(fold, 1:DIM1));                % label of the training set
labelTE = lab(DIV(fold, DIM1+1:DIM2));  % label of the test set
numClasses = max(y);

siz=[224 224];  %  input size of ResNet50

% build training set
clear nome trainingImages
for pattern = 1:DIM1                % for all the images 
    IM = NX{DIV(fold,pattern)};     % image
    IM = imresize(IM,[siz(1) siz(2)]);
    trainingImages(:,:,:,pattern) = IM;
end

DIM = length(y);  % number of images of the training set

% buid testing set
for pattern = ceil(DIM1)+1:ceil(DIM2)
    IM = NX{DIV(fold,pattern)};
    IM = imresize(IM,[siz(1) siz(2)]);
    testImages(:,:,:,pattern-ceil(DIM1)) = uint8(IM);
end
```

In the above codes, the value of DIM is 880, and  trainingImages : 224 x 224 x 3 x 880 uint8 array

The DATA in the above code is =>  DATA: 1x5 cell array = {1x1320 cell}  {[111111.....]}   {3x1320 double}   {880}    {[1320]}  )

But, I could not create a .mat file from our 10000 images which will be classified into 7 classes. I need your help.

Could you please write the codes that can construct a .mat file (from 10000 images to classify into 7 classes) to use in the above codes

I have written these

```
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpeg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);
result = cell(1,10000);
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles) 
      baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name; 
      fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName); 
      fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName); 
      imageArray= imread(fullFileName); 
      result{k} = imageArray; 
    end 
    save ('db2.mat', 'result');
```

But the format of the "db2.mat" is different from the "DatasColor_38.mat" file. Thus, I could not use it in the above code.
Please help me to overcome this issue :((

Comment: I have written ==> for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
  baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  imageArray= imread(fullFileName);
  result{k} = imageArray;
end
save ('db2.mat', result);   But the format of the "db2.mat" is different from the "DatasColor_38.mat" file. Thus, I could not use it in the above code.  Please help me to overcome this issue  :((

Comment: I need your help since our images are in a folder and I don't know how to create the mat file from the images to be able to use in the above codes.

Comment: Please [edit] your post, rather than adding information in comments. Especially code is hard to read in comments. But `save('db2.mat', result)` looks wrong. Should be `save db2.mat result` or `save('db2.mat', 'result')`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have edited the question as you said.  I hope, someone can help me to solve this problem  :((